# If Posted After Date

Tags: templates, date

I need to get a different "get_template_part" based on the date and category. I have changed the outlay of the category which means any post in that category before today's date wont be able to use the new template but needs to still use the old one.

```
if ( in_category( 'photographer-interviews' )) {
 get_template_part( 'content', 'interview' );
} else {
 get_template_part( 'content', 'blog' );
}
```

So i need to also check if the post inside the "photographer-interviews" was posted after today. If it was continue to the new template if not keep using the old one (blog).

Comment: And by "today" you mean 15th Aug, 2013? Which template should be used when exactly?

Comment: The interview template needs to be used for anything posted after 15th Aug, 2013 in the photographer-interviews category.

Comment: u have post object or something? if you are in loop you can use  if (strtotime(the_date('', '', '', false)) <=  strtotime(yesterday)) {
         get_template_part( 'content', 'interview' );
    }
    else {
         get_template_part( 'content', 'blog' );
    }

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of comparing dates. the following is perhaps the simplest (untested):

```
if ( in_category( 'photographer-interviews' ) && strtotime( get_the_date( 'c' ) ) > 1376524800 ) {
 get_template_part( 'content', 'interview' );
} else {
 get_template_part( 'content', 'blog' );
}
```

1376524800 is the Unix timestamp for 00:00 (GMT) on August 15 - that is, midnight of the 14th. So posts with a publication date of the 15th will return true.

If you literally only want posts *after* the 15th you'd use 1376611200.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to compare the post date against a set date.

**Get the post date**

This will retrieve the date in the format yyyy-mm-dd as in 2013-07-31. The Wordpress Codex has more info on [the_date()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date).

```
$post_date = the_date( 'Y-m-d', '', '', false );
```

**Specify cutoff date**

Specify the date to compare the post date against. Use the same date format as in step 1.

```
$cutoff_date = '2013-08-14';
```

**Convert dates**

Convert the dates to a timestamp string using PHP's [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function so that they can be compared. Add this to the code from above.

```
$post_date = strtotime( the_date( 'Y-m-d', '', '', false ) );
$cutoff_date = strtotime( '2013-08-14' );
```

**Compare dates**

```
$post_date > $cutoff_date
```

**All together now**

And here's the complete code.

```
$post_date = strtotime( the_date( 'Y-m-d', '', '', false ) );
$cutoff_date = strtotime( '2013-08-14' );
if ( in_category( 'photographer-interviews' ) && $post_date > $cutoff_date ) {
    get_template_part( 'content', 'interview' );
} else {
    get_template_part( 'content', 'blog' );
}
```

Comment: Your code does not take timezones into account - though I don't know if that degree of accuracy is required by the OP.

Comment: @vancoder Good point. I hadn't considered that level of accuracy.

Comment: Good explanation otherwise though.

Answer (score 0):

Marvelous, I used the idea to switch between bootstrap 3 and 4.

```
$post_date = strtotime( get_the_date( 'Y-m-d', '', '', false ) );
$cutoff_date = strtotime( '2019-12-31' );
if (is_single() && $post_date > $cutoff_date) {
echo '<bootstrap 4 code>';
} elseif (is_single() && $post_date < $cutoff_date) { echo '<bootstrap 3 code>';}
elseif (!is_single()) {echo '<bootstrap 4 code>';}
```